# Java does not provide DoubleCache or FloatCache in ValueOf(double/float) method

Tags: java, integer

I have seen that java provides IntegerCache,ShortCache,ByteCahce.. but there is no cache logic in Double/Float class. Is it because use of double values will not be that much frequent , compared to int?

Comment: The cache policy in the integral wrappers is based on the premise that there are certain integral values that are used very often. There is no such premise for FP types.

Comment: Yes, That's what i had in my mind but wanted to confirm it.Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doc of [Double#valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28double%29) suggests that there is a cache but there isn't

> Returns a Double instance representing the specified double value. If a new Double instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Double(double), **as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values.**

Values from -128 to 127 are cached from all three you have mentioned which are used while auto-boxing.

Comment: Yes,As per JDK 6 source code,   public static Double valueOf(double d) {
        return new Double(d);
    } ..same new instance is being created.. Assuming JDK 7 will also have same source code.

Comment: @AKS Java 6 doc also says same [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28double%29)

Comment: @ALLL.. So what should I conclude here? something is wrong with javadocs?

Comment: First of all, it is not wise to assume the next version won't change this. Second, there's nothing wrong with the Javadoc. Using factory is advisable.

Comment: Hmm, I've pondered this before.  The documentation is probably just allowing for the possibility of caching, whereas the *implementer* realized the characteristics of caching doubles/floats rarely yielded appreciable benefits.